# Circular Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the following prolog code:

```
equiAngularTriangle(T) :-
    equiLateralTriangle(T).

equiLateralTriangle(T) :-
    equiAngularTriangle(T).
```

Is there a way to keep the interpreter from asking the same question twice? For instance, if I ask `equiAngularTriangle(t)`, then it's going to ask `equiLateralTriangle(t)`, then ask `equiLateralTriangle(t)`, but it should know not to pursue that last one again, because the same question is on the "query stack".

Is there an option or some special syntax that lets Prolog behave the way I want it to?

Comment: How do you check if the statement is true? Do you also have a rule that will finalize this query? Or else: How does it know if it is either one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the prolog implementation supports tabling or you are using XSB then you could use it and get the desired behaviour.

You could also add a state argument:

```
%State = [Checked_for_equiAngular, Checked_for_equiLateral]

equiAngularTriangle(T, [_,false]) :-
    equiLateralTriangle(T, [true,true]).

equiLateralTriangle(T, [false,_]) :-
    equiAngularTriangle(T, [true,true]).
```

of course you will need to modify the rest of the clauses.

The last (and best imo) option is to rewrite your predicates. I guess that your code will be similar to this example:

```
ang(T):-
  foo(T).
ang(T):-
  lat(T).

lat(T):-
  bar(T).
lat(T):-
  ang(T).
```

so you could simply write:

```
ang(T):-
  foo(T).
ang(T):-
  bar(T).

lat(T):-
  ang(T).
```

normally you will use some wrapper predicates if instead of foo(T) you had foo1(T),foo2(T) etc

Answer (score 1):

Try [XSB Prolog](http://xsb.sourceforge.net/about.html). It implements tabling which will short-circuit evaluation like in your case. You need to tell it which predicates should be tabled, though.